# Easy redstone memory

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I want to make a simple one-bit storage to check if someone else entered my house. For the person detector, I use the magic plate from thaumcraft. But how can I build a circuit memory which changes it's state if it was triggered and keeps it until an reset button is pressed? I would prefer to use redpower gates or something similar instead of bare redstone to keep it more compact.

Comment: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Memory_circuit#RS-NOR_Latches
And these are just (some of) the silent ones.  Not shown are some of the really easy piston versions.

Comment: Also, http://technicpack.wikia.com/wiki/RS_Latch is what you want for a compact implementation.

Comment: What version of the pack are you running, specifically?

Comment: @Unionhawk Direwolf20 v5.3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a RS latch. You can build this with vanilla components like so:

[image: RS latch]

With the pressure plate powering one side of the input, and the "reset button" powering the other.

Or, since you are running a version of the FTB pack that still has RedPower2, you can use the [RedPower2 RS latch](http://integratedredstone.wikispaces.com/Redpower+Logic). It's up to you on how you want to wire it (obviously the wiring is much simpler with RedPower2).